# Start/Stop window service of VPN remote server

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried to start/stop window service of VPN remote server, but no luck.

Now I can start/stop window server of remote server on same domain with my PC, as describe in [Start A Remote Service From C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226871/start-a-remote-service-from-c-sharp/3230638#3230638) .

I tried to used this approach: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/15950/windows-services--remote-machine.aspx but it throws exception `WSANO_DATA - 11004 when getting the host name` (at line: `String hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(_Server).HostName;`).

Sample code here (.NET 4.0)

```
ConnectionOptions cred = new ConnectionOptions();

cred.Username = _UsrNm;

cred.Password = _Pass;

String hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(_Server).HostName;

ManagementScope srvScope;

srvScope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", hostName), cred);

ManagementPath win32Path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");

ManagementClass services;

services = new ManagementClass(srvScope, win32Path, null);
```

Please give me your advice or opinion if any.

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Impersonate as describe in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx, using logon type = LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS and logon provider = LOGON32_WINNT50, and it works for me (over VPN and window server 2008 installed in remote server.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2a8ca3c8-e1ec-490a-a7e5-5ec533080f00/

Comment: Tks for your reply, unfortunately it does not help me.
I will try to use Impersonate over VPN.